# How to pass an argument to evaluateJavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qwebview

```
for (int i = 0; i < centerPointsList.size (); i++)
    {
        QVariant         holdInformation = map->page ()->mainFrame ()->evaluateJavaScript (QString ("constructFileName (%1).arg (centerPointsList[0].toFloat())"));
        QList <QVariant> allListObj      = holdInformation.toList ();
        QList <QVariant> fileNamesList   = allListObj[0].toList ();

        std :: cout << fileNamesList[0].toFloat() << "================= \n";

    }
```

This results in:

> "SyntaxError: Parse error on line:1 Source:undefined"
>   Segmentation fault

I am guessing that the error is in the way I am passing the list item to the function `evaluateJavaScript`.

UPDATE:

---

I tried this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < centerPointsList.size (); i++)
 {
   QVariant holdInformation = map->page ()->mainFrame ()->evaluateJavaScript (QString ("constructFileName (%1)").arg (centerPointsList [0].toFloat ()));
```

which resulted in:

> "TypeError: Result of expression 'centerPointFileName.split' [undefined] is not a function. on line:65 Source:file:///.../index.html"

The function `constructFileName` (in Javascript) is as follows:

```
function constructFileName (centerPointFileName)
 {
   var removeSpaces = centerPointFileName.split (" ");
   var fileNameWithoutSpaces = "", i;
   for (i = 0; i < removeSpaces.length; i++)
       fileNameWithoutSpaces = fileNameWithoutSpaces + removeSpaces [i];
```

Comment: Are you looking for `QString("constructFileName (%1)").arg(centerPointsList[0].toFloat())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your update, your JavaScript function expects a string argument. The simplest approach should look like this:

```
QString info = QString("constructFileName('%1')").arg(centerPointsList[i].toFloat());
QVariant holdInformation = map->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(info);
```

However, in general this is not completely safe - if the interpolated argument `%1` contains backslashes, double quotes or other special symbols, they need to be escaped first. I cannot comment on how that should be done, since I have never worked with Qt :)